# Cant find Symbol error

Tags: java, class, methods

The compiler gives me an error message saying it can't find movies[x].getTitle() and movies[x].getYear. I've been wondering if it's a problem with going through the interface to get to the classes

Here is the error:

```
MathewBorumP5.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.printf("%-26s%-6s%-10s%-9s%-11s\n", movies[x]
.getTitle(),

^
symbol:   method getTitle()
location: interface Profitable
MathewBorumP5.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
                            movies[x].getYear(), movies[x].calcRevenue(),
                                     ^
symbol:   method getYear()
location: interface Profitable
2 errors
```

Here is my client class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathewBorumP5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        boolean restart = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Profitable[] movies = new Profitable[6];
        movies[0] = new Animated("Beauty and the Beast", "Gary Trousdale", 1991,
        10.0, 5.0, 2.0);
        movies[1] = new Animated("Peter Pan", "Clyde Geronimi", 1953, 2.0, 1.2,
        .5);
        movies[2] = new Documentary("Planet Earth", "Alastair Fothergill", 2006,
        10, 20, 5);
    movies[3] = new Documentary("Drain the Ocean", "Steve Nichols", 2009, 9,
        2,3);
    movies[4] = new Drama("The Shawshank Redemption", "Frank Darabont",
        1994, 89, 7, 2);
    movies[5] = new Drama("The Godfather", "Francis Coppola", 1972, 10, 3,
        5);

    do {
        menu();
        System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 - 5: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                item1(movies);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                restart = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("You didn't enter a number between 1"
                    + " and 5.\n");
                break;
        }
    } while(restart == true);
}

public static void menu() {
    System.out.print("Warren Moore Movie Menu\n");
    System.out.print("1. Show the list of movies in the array\n");
    System.out.print("2. Display the total number of movies and the total" +
        " revenues\n");
    System.out.print("3. Search movie by title\n");
    System.out.print("4. Display movies sorted by profit in decreasing" +
        " order\n");
    System.out.print("5. Exit\n");
}

public static void item1(Profitable[] movies) {
    double revenue;
    System.out.printf("%-26s%-6s%-10s%-9s%-11s\n", "Title", "Year", 
    "Revenue", "Profit", "Category");
    for(int x = 0; x <= 6; x++) {
        revenue = movies[x].calcRevenue();
        System.out.printf("%-26s%-6s%-10s%-9s%-11s\n", movies[x].getTitle(),
            movies[x].getYear(), movies[x].calcRevenue(),
            movies[x].calcProfit(revenue), movies[x].category());
    }
}
}
```

Here is my superclass:

```
public class Movie implements Profitable {
protected String title;
protected String director;
protected int year;
protected double productionCost;
private int totalMovies = 0;

public Movie() {
    totalMovies++;
}
public Movie(String newTitle, String newDirector, int newYear,
    double newCost) {
    totalMovies++;
    title = newTitle;
    director = newDirector;
    year = newYear;
    productionCost = newCost;
}

public int getTotalMovies() {
    return totalMovies;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDirector() {
    return director;
}

public void setDirector(String director) {
    this.director = director;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public double getProductionCost() {
    return productionCost;
}

public void setProductionCost(double productionCost) {
    this.productionCost = productionCost;
}

public String toString() {
    return "";
}
}
```

Here are my separate classes.
    public class Animated extends Movie implements Profitable {
    private double rate;
    private double income;

```
public Animated() {
    super();
}

public Animated(String title, String director, int year, double cost,
    double rate, double income) {
    super(title, director, year, cost);
    this.rate = rate;
    this.income = income;
}

public double getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public double getIncome() {
    return income;
}

public void setIncome(double income) {
    this.income = income;
}

public String category() {
    return "Animated";
}

public double calcRevenue() {
    return (income * rate);
}

public double calcProfit(double revenue) {
    return (revenue - super.productionCost);
}

public String toString() {
    return (super.toString() + "");
}
}
```

Number 2

```
public class Documentary extends Movie implements Profitable {
private int distributors;
private double premium;

public Documentary() {
    super();
}

public Documentary(String title, String director, int year, double cost,
    int distributors, double premium) {
    super(title, director, year, cost);
    this.distributors = distributors;
    this.premium = premium;
}

public int getDistributors() {
    return distributors;
}

public void setDistributors(int distributors) {
    this.distributors = distributors;
}

public double getPremium() {
    return premium;
}

public void setPremium(double premium) {
    this.premium = premium;
}

public String category() {
    return "Documentary";
}

public double calcRevenue() {
    return (distributors * premium);
}

public double calcProfit(double revenue)  {
    return (revenue - super.productionCost);
}

public String toString() {
    return (super.toString() + "");
}
}
```

Number 3

```
public class Drama extends Movie implements Profitable {
private int tickets;
private double avgPrice;

public Drama() {
    super();
}

public Drama(String title, String director, int year, double cost,
    int tickets, double avgPrice) {
    super(title, director, year, cost);
    this.tickets = tickets;
    this.avgPrice = avgPrice;
}

public int getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}

public void setTickets(int tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
}

public String category() {
    return "Drama";
}

public double calcRevenue() {
    return (tickets * avgPrice);
}

public double calcProfit(double revenue) {
    return (revenue - super.productionCost);
}

public String toString() {
    return (super.toString() + "");
}
}
```

And finally my interface.

```
public interface Profitable {
    public abstract String category();
    public abstract double calcRevenue();
    public abstract double calcProfit(double revenue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Profitable interface doesn't have the methods that you're trying to call, and so the compiler is correct to complain about this to you. The array variable doesn't know what type of object each array item might hold, and in fact one could hold one type of item only to have it changed later, so it makes sense for the compiler to behave this way. A kludge would be to test each item held by the array to see what type it actually is, say by using instanceof, but this is a very fragile solution and is not recommended. Safest is to only call Profitable methods on Profitable array items and to try to use the magic of polymorphism to allow each object to do different behaviors for the same method call.

Note that if all of the items held by the array will always be Movie or Movie child items, then by all means use an array of Movie rather than an array of Profitable.

Comment: Thanks so I should use "Movie[] movies = new Movie[6];" instead?

Comment: @user2226282: If all the contents of the array will be Movie or Movie child objects, then yes, try it.

Comment: I did it, but now it can't find calcRevenue, calcProfit, or category. It only recognizes the methods in the superclass.

Comment: @user2226282: you don't show your Movie class, but I am going to assume that it doesn't implement the Profitable interface, and that is a mistake. Fix the mistake and have it implement the interface.

Comment: I added the interface to movie and got the same errors plus one that says Movie is not abstract and does not override abstract method calcProfit(double) in Profitable. Also I added the movie class up above

Comment: @user2226282: either make Movie abstract or implement the interface methods inside of Movie just as the error is telling you you should do. Have you read your chapter on use of interfaces yet? If not, consider doing that now.

Comment: Okay, I get what the problem is. I can't add or subtract any methods from any of the classes(my professor's rules) so I can't implement Profitable in Movie.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the issue is with your Profitable interface.
When you create the array item(Profitable[] movies), this means that only the methods defined in this interface will be available to you.

An array of Movie objects is probably what you are after here.  All of those objects appear extend Movie and implement Profitable, so you will able to access everything this way.